# I get a System.NullReferenceException when trying to use HttpWebReaspone on xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

When I tried this code in a normal Console app project it works, but it doesnt work on xamarin, the exception occurs in

"                 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
"

```
                string html = string.Empty;
                string url = $"https://stackoverflow.com/";
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

Comment: have you tried using HttpClient?  As we previously discussed, WebRequest and its associated classes have been marked obsolete

Comment: how do I do that exaclty? @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest trying [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) instead

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```